# In python 3.4.2 this code throws a TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffprobe

TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

when running this code in python3.4.2

```
import subprocess

def getLength(filename):
  result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", filename],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
  return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, reading subprocess's stdout yields `bytes` instead of `str`.

Using `bytes` literal will solve your problem (prepend `b` before the string literals)

```
return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if b"Duration" in x]
```

BTW, `readlines` is not needed. Simply iterate the `result.stdout`:

```
return [x for x in result.stdout if b"Duration" in x]
```